# Sending message chats to the bottom of the list and is archive the only option?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, chat, chat-history

I was reading [this](https://faq.whatsapp.com/1426887324388733/?cms_platform=android&helpref=platform_switcher) about archiving chat and it says:

> You won’t get notifications for archived chats unless you’re mentioned
> or replied to.

Does that mean that if I have a chat with an individual and the last message to them was from me, if I archive it, when the person sends a new message it will considered a reply and I will get a notification?

What I was trying to do is "push" some chats to the bottom of the list and archive seems the only option to do such "housekeeping". I want to make sure I don't lose a reply/message too.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*(This answer was based on WhatsApp 2.24.6.77 and testing between 2 WhatsApp accounts on different devices)*</sup>

> What I was trying to do is "push" some chats to the bottom of the list and archive seems the only option to do such "housekeeping".

Correct. As of this version, archiving is the only way to hide chats from the main chat lists without deleting them.

> Does that mean that if I have a chat with an individual and the last message to them was from me, if I archive it, when the person sends a new message it will considered a reply and I will get a notification?

Archived individual chats won't give any notifications, either if the sender sends a message normally or replies to a specific message by the receiver (by swiping a message horizontally).

The quoted remark about getting notifications when being mentioned (using @username) or replied to *only applies in a group chat*.

To still get notified when new messages come in archived chats, turn off the "Keep chats archived" option in Chat settings, but there is no way to apply it per chat. All archived chats are affected, and new messages will unarchive them.